# theme_hook_suggestions based on empty field

Tags: theming

I'm trying to implement theme_hook_suggestions in preprocess node template based on the fact that a field (field_logo) is empty or not.

The template change is not working.

Can anyone help?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
function community_alpha_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if(($node->type == 'advertorial') && !$teaser && $node_top){
    $advertorial_type = $node->field_logo['und'][0]['tid'];
    if(!empty($advertorial_type)){
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'] = 'node__advertorial';
    }else{
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'] = 'node__advertorial__alt';
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there was a problem with the first conditional loop.
I also removed ['und'], [0] and ['tid'] from field_logo.

So here's the final code that seems to work.

Thanks for the help.

```
function community_alpha_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if($node->type == 'advertorial'){
    $advertorial_type = $node->field_logo;
    if(!empty($advertorial_type)){
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__advertorial';
    }else{
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__advertorial__alt';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the cache after making changes in the template.php file.

For Drupal 7 version please run below command to clear the cache and check aftewards.

drush cc all

For Drupal 8 version please run below command to clear the cache and check afterwards.

drush cache-clear

Comment: Off course, that's the first thing i did.

Comment: try with 
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__advertorial';

Comment: Thanks parth,.k, i also tried that as well. Other than that, the code makes sense? I wasn't sure about how i used "empty"in the conditional loop.

Comment: R u sure ? u have tried below code 
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__advertorial';
and clear the cache ?

Comment: checked if its going to if else part or not ?

Comment: I did add the empty braces and empty cache, as you suggested... Not working. (Sorry I'm not sure to understand your last comment.)

Comment: I mean to check if your code is executing on if and else part by printing die () on either of them ?

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that. (I don't no much about php).

Comment: Please confirm r u able to debug the code ?

Comment: Thanks for following up, i appreciate. I'm actually about to test it this morning so I'll let you know the results  soon.

Comment: Please confirm r u able to debug the code ?